# Why limit of (1+1/n) is not 0?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm learning calculus. The formal definition for lim is:

For every `x` you can find an `N` that for every `n` larger than `N` $|A_n-limit|$ will be smaller that `x`.

This is the function: $a_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$

It's seems that the statment is true for `limit 0` *since every `x` I will choose if I increment 'n' it's always get closer and closer to 0*.

Comment: As $n \to \infty$, $\frac{1}{n} \to 0 \implies a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n} \to 1$.

Comment: Why do you think the numbers get closer and closer to 0? They never even get below 1.

Comment: Solving for $n$ the inequation $\left\lvert1+\frac1n-0\right\rvert<x$ is an easy exercise of high school algebra. If you do so, you'll notice that the solution set is bounded above for all $x>0$.

Comment: @Saucy, not true; for $x=42$ the solution set is all of $\mathbb N_+$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, true. Guess it's back to the chalkboard for me!

Comment: It should have been for all $0<x<1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pick $x=1/2$. Then $|1+\frac1n-0|\gt x$ for any $n$, so $0$ is not the limit.

Comment: Thanks. You right. for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ There is no N that will give less than that.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{n}$ gets closer and closer to zero, in the limit it is zero, but you still have a 1 to deal with. $ \lim_{n\to \infty}1+\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}1+\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} =1+0=1$

Answer (score 0):

If we take sequence An=1+1/n then from definition |An-0|<€, for predefined small positive quantity. Then we find 1+1/n<€ i.e. n>1/(€-1) taking as m=[1/(€-1)] where [.] denote greatest positive integer. m is very large and n is larger than large number so n->∞ clearly this result is valid for any n€Z, Z is set of all integer.

Answer (score 0):

`1+1/n` means $1+\frac{1}{n}$, which goes to $1$ as explained in the other answers.

But if you erroneously think `1+1/n` means $\frac{1+1}{n}$, then in fact that does go to $0$.